# Как сделать задержку на наведение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет

Есть такой код:

```
function timeOutHover() {
    $('.work-examples__li').hover(
        // при наведении
        function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('newhover');
                },
                1000); // 1 sek
        },
        // при уходе
        function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('newhover');
                },
                1000); // 1 sek
        }
    );
}
```

Я стараюсь сделать, что бы при наведении наведение срабатывало не сразу, а черех 1с, так как таких блоков несколько и если быстро по ним водить курсор, то выглядит не очень.Данный код не работает, не знаю почему

Comment: А в чём проблема сделать это на css с transition delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с паузой, перед установкой класса при наведении, отсутствует эффект моргания при быстром наведении по блокам ... но самое лучшее решение в первом коментарии @Doofy

```js
var timer, pause = 400;
$("ul").on("mouseenter mouseleave", "li", function(event) {
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
  var that = this;
  if (event.type == "mouseenter") {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      that.classList.add("newhover")
    }, pause)
  } else this.classList.remove("newhover")
})
```

```css
ul {
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #868686;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  font-family: 'Montez', cursive;
}
li.newhover a {
  color: #f70211;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="work-examples__li">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="work-examples__li">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="work-examples__li">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="work-examples__li">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Большой спасибо, рони!

Answer (score 4):

Через CSS же проще:

```
.work-examples__li {
   transition: 1s;
}

.work-examples__li:hover {
   // здесь все изменения, которые должны произойти при наведении
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не учитываете, что контекст выполнения у функции внутри `hover` и функции, которую вы передаете внутрь `setTimeout`, разный. В данном случае при вызове функции из `setTimeout` переменная `this` будет указывать на корневой объект `window`.

Рабочий пример:

```js
    $('.work-examples__li').hover(
        // при наведении
        function(){
            var self = this
            setTimeout(function() {
                    //здесь this указывает уже на window
                    $(self).addClass('newhover');
                },
                300); // 1 sek
        },
        // при уходе
        function(){
            var self = this
            setTimeout(function() {
                    $(self).removeClass('newhover');
                },
                300); // 1 sek
        }
    );
```

```css
.newhover{
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work-examples__li">test</div>
<div class="work-examples__li">test</div>
<div class="work-examples__li">test</div>
<div class="work-examples__li">test</div>
```

P.S. но в общем-то с помощью CSS это делается удобнее и проще.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно же, что this не передается в вашем коде. Делаем так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .work-examples__li {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      margin: 5px;
      float: left;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .newhover {
      border-width: 2px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.work-examples__li').hover(
        function() {
          var that = this;
          setTimeout(function() {
              $(that).addClass('newhover');
            },
            1000); // 1 sek
        },
        function() {
          var that = this;
          setTimeout(function() {
              $(that).removeClass('newhover');
            },
            1000); // 1 sek
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="work-examples__li"></div>
  <div class="work-examples__li"></div>
  <div class="work-examples__li"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ, это ПОЧТИ то, то нужно. Если в вашем коде начать быстро перемещать курсор по блокам, то они начинают опять быстро ховериться без тайм аута. Это можно исправить?